# priority-web-sdk: uploadFile

Tags: javascript, erp

I'm trying to upload a file from a `<input type="file">` HTML tag, using the [uploadFile](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/form/#uploadFile) method.

The [uploadFile](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/form/#uploadFile) promise resolves, but with a <100 progress value - it's still uploading. So I need to wait until it finishes, but after the first promise resolves how do I keep updating the [FileUploadResult](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/form/#FileUploadResult) please?

My example page is [here](https://erpdemo.emerge-it.co.uk/ui/upload2.html).

```
    function UploadFile(curform, file) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {                
            var FileUploadResult;
            var check = function () {
                if (FileUploadResult.isLast) {
                    resolve(FileUploadResult)
                } else {
                    console.log(FileUploadResult);
                    setTimeout(check, 1000);
                }
            };           

            curform.uploadFile(file).then(Result => {
                FileUploadResult = Result
                check();
            }).catch(er => { reject(er) })

        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Promise` here. Use `callbacks`. 
As it is written in the documentation :

`uploadFile(file, [onSuccess], [onError]) ⇒ Promise`.

Answer (score 0):

@simon-barnett, I encountered the same problem.  Everything else I'm doing is with promises and `.then()` statements aside from the `uploadFile()` call.

```
curForm.uploadFile(file,uploadSuccess, uploadError);

function uploadSuccess(r) {
  if (r.isLast) {
    curForm.newRow()
            .then(() => curForm.fieldUpdate("EXTFILENAME", r.file))
            .then(() => curForm.saveRow(1)) //Save and Close curForm
  }
}
```

What I think is happening is that the `.isLast` Boolean is not being properly updated once the upload is finished, even if the `progress` gets to 100.  The callback method does not get hung up on this, returns the promise and sets the `.isLast`Boolean correctly.

I believe this is true as of version 1.5 (although I'm having trouble getting the version # right now)

UPDATE: As per the documentation, as of version 2.0.1 the `.isLast` property was removed.  As of version 2.1.0 we now have `FileProgress` and `FileResult`.  This should allow for `.uploadFile` to be called as a promise instead of with call backs, although I have not tested this yet myself.